# Hex code for clear color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uicolor

My ques may be silly. Is there an hexa code for `[UIColor clearColor]`? If so, what is the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hexa code? you mean like `#00000000` ?

Comment: Sorry but you need color for a clearColor?

Comment: @MarcoPace I am in a need to use only hexa codes for color. So, checked for the option for using code for clearColor.

Comment: Then i guess `#00000000` would represent it. `[UIColor clearColor]` is the same as `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f]`

Comment: Every color might be a clear. Just set alpha channel to 0.

Comment: this link will help you http://www.color-hex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIColor *clearColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CGFloat red = 0; 
CGFloat green = 0; 
CGFloat blue = 0; 
CGFloat alpha = 0; 

[clearColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

NSLog(@"red: %.3f, green: %.3f, blue: %.3f, alpha: %.3f",
red, green, blue, alpha);

NSLog(@"red: 0x%02x, green: 0x%02x, blue: 0x%02x, alpha: 0x%02x",
      (int)(red*255.0), (int)(green*255.0), (int)(blue*255.0), (int)(alpha*255.0));
```

NSLog output:

```
red: 0.000, green: 0.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 0.000
red: 0x00, green: 0x00, blue: 0x00, alpha: 0x00
```

Comment: Hmm i think alpha should be zero, did you test run it? when i do it outputs `red: 0.000, green: 0.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 0.000`.

Comment: @beryllium nice catch, I posted my test case result by accident, corrected.

Answer (score 8):

**RGBA Hex Code** for ClearColor:
`NNNNNN00` whereas N may be any hex-value (0-F).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, [hexadecimal color codes](http://www.december.com/html/spec/colorhex.html) are made up of RRGGBB values, whereas `[UIColor clearColor]` depends very much on there being an alpha component.

So the answer is "nope", there's no hexa code for `clearColor`.

Answer (score 0):

I like using hex colours in my configuration, so I modified a commonly used macro to split RGBA hex (eg. #00000055 semi-transparent black) into a UIColor with alpha:

```
#define UIColorFromRGBA(rgbaValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbaValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbaValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
blue:((float)((rgbaValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
alpha:((float)(rgbaValue & 0xFF))/255.0 ]
```

Example usage:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBA(0x00000055);
```